Existence of Limit from Gelfand's Formula
Let $A$ be a square matrix over $\mathbb C$ with spectral radius $\rho(A) > 0$ and $||A||$ denote the operator norm of $A$. By Gelfand's formula, we have $||A^n||^{1/n} \to \rho(A)$ as $n \to \infty$ and hence $a_n := \frac{\rho(A)}{||A^n||^{1/n}} \to 1$. (I require $\rho(A) > 0$ because otherwise, we would have $A^n = 0$ for all sufficiently large $n$.)
If we consider instead $a_n^n = \frac{\rho(A)^n}{||A^n||}$, does $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^n$ also exist? An easy bound is $\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n^n \leq 1$ since $||A^n|| \geq \rho(A)^n$, so if the limit exists, it has to lie in $[0, 1]$.
One way to prove the limit exists would be to show that the sequence $(a_n^n)_n$ is monotonically decreasing, in which case the limit would simply be the infimum. To get this, one would need $||A^{n + 1}|| \geq \rho(A)||A^n||$, which clearly holds for $n = 0$. However, I see no reason it should be  true in general for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb N$ as unit vectors $v$ which maximize $||A^nv||$ may not be eigenvectors of $A$.

By homogeneity, we may assume $\rho(A) = 1$, and we're interested in $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|A^n\|$.
We have $A = S J S^{-1}$ where $J$ is the Jordan canonical form of $A$, and $S$ is an invertible matrix. Then
$A^n = S J^n S^{-1}$ and $J^n = S^{-1} A^n S$,
so $$(\|S\| \|S^{-1}\|)^{-1} \|J^n\| \le |A^n\| \le \|S\| \|S^{-1}\| \|J^n\| $$
If $A$ has at least one Jordan block of size $> 1$ for an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of absolute value $1$, I claim $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|A^n\| = \infty$.  For then there are nonzero vectors $v$ and $w$ such that $A v = \lambda v$ and $A w = v + \lambda w$.  By induction we have $A^n w = n \lambda^{n-1} v + \lambda^n w$, and so $\|A^n w \| \to \infty$.
On the other hand, if all Jordan blocks for eigenvalues of absolute value $1$ have size $1$, then $\|J^n\|$ is bounded and so is $\|A^n\|$.  The limit may or may exist. For example, consider $A = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr c & -1\cr}$, for which
$A^n = A$ if $n$ is odd and the identity matrix $I$ if $n$ is even.
